# Simulating enter/send key in android appium tests

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium

I am trying to automate one part of an android application I wrote. I this activity I have a edittext which is used to enter a product number.

Once the product number is entered the user clicks on the software keyboards send button to initiate a search for that product, however I am not able to simulate the softkeyboard's send/enter key using java-appium.

The following code works well in android 4.4.4 and below but not in android 6.0+

```
element.sendKeys(productNumber + "\n");
```

The code below does not work either

```
element.sendKeys(productNumber + Keys.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that only this solution is the most reliable one - mocking manual submit button tap.

```
static void submit() {
    Dimension screen = mobileDriver.manage().window().getSize();
    mobileDriver.tap(1, screen.getWidth() - 20, screen.getHeight() - 20);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input, let me try it out right away.

Comment: Sorry, I write in Groovy. Please see update shortly.

Comment: Is there a way to sense if the softkeyboard is open and show it if it is hidden?

Comment: I have not thought about it. I guess there should be an element to verify. I know for iOS it is `//UIAKeyboard` but I cannot remember Android case.

Comment: Only this worked for me among many options. Thanks for that first. But this won't work well in case of Split window in Android 7.0.